# How can I make a google sheets query for dates that fall in "this week"

Tags: date, google-sheets

I'm trying to put a query in one google sheet tab that pulls in data from another tab (Called Confirmed Shoots), based on one "date" column in the Confirmed Shoots tab. I want to pull in anything from the current week, probably taken from the week number (WEEKNUM).

I have a similar formula working in another tab where I'm pulling in everything scheduled for tomorrow, which is:

`=query('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select G,J,I,H,C,E,F,K,L,N,D Where G=date"""&text(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ")`

I also found a way to pull "this week" from a date with this IF formula-

`=IF(WEEKNUM(G2)=WEEKNUM(NOW()),"Yes","")`

I'm struggling with the syntax, trying to combine the two. I want it to be something like:

`=query('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select G,J,I,H,C,E,F,K,L,N,D Where (WEEKNUM(G2)=WEEKNUM(NOW()),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ")")`

or

`=query('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select G,J,I,H,C,E,F,K,L,N,D Where (WEEKNUM(G2)=WEEKNUM(NOW())`

Both of these are giving me errors though. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use FILTER instead

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=FILTER(QUERY('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select G,J,I,H,C,E,F,K,L,N,D"), WEEKNUM('Confirmed Shoots'!G1:G)=WEEKNUM(NOW()))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This code worked, thank you! Do you know where in there I could add the order I want, like "order by H asc." Would that go after "select" in the formula, or later on?

Comment: @Michelle, Use SORT function. `=SORT (FILTER(QUERY('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select G,J,I,H,C,E,F,K,L,N,D"), WEEKNUM('Confirmed Shoots'!G1:G)=WEEKNUM(NOW())), 4,1)`